# Nested Group-By in Lambda expression not getting expected result

Tags: c#, json, lambda

I have a MySQL table which has data like shown below

```
Column1        Column2      Column3

AAA               ABC           123

AAA               ABC           234

AAA               DEF           1111

AAA               DEF           2222
```

I'm trying to create JSON data from it. The expected JSON result is:

```
AAA 
   ABC 
      123
      234
   DEF
      1111
      2222
```

Thought to use nested group by statements, but unable to reach the expected result. Please help me to form the JSON string. The rule to perform the nesting is like:

Parent --> Multiple children --> Multiple Grand children

Comment: Format the json in your question and check out [ask] - good luck!

Comment: Thanks i will follow.

Comment: Why don't you just write some code to iterate through the columns making up a JSON string in a hierarchy?

Comment: what have you tried so far? where do you have this data? are you using LINQ to SQL? or do you have them in object colllection? please add more details.

Comment: group by column 1 then group by column 2 (the child name was not changed instead of show first child only).

Comment: var disp = menu.GroupBy(a => a.module).Select(b => b.First()).Select(c => new BL.Objects.menu()
{id = c.id,
name = c.module,
items = menu.Where(f => f.module == c.module).GroupBy(g => g.screen).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).Select(j => new BL.Objects.submenu()
{id = c.id,
name = c.screen,
items = menu.Where(k => k.screen == j.screen && k.module == c.module).Select(l => new BL.Objects.sub_submenu()
{id = l.id,
name = l.name
})
})
});

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

**Using GroupBy**

```
    var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Column1).Select(y => new
    {
        C1 = y.Key,
        C1Children = y.GroupBy(z => z.Column2).Select(m => new
        {
            C2 = m.Key,
            C2Children = m.Select(n => n.Column3)
        })
    });

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsonResult = serializer.Serialize(test);
```

**Without GroupBy**

```
    var result = list.Select(x => x.Column1).Distinct().Select(y => new
    {
        Level1 = y,
        Level2List = list.Where(z => z.Column1 == y).Select(y1 => y1.Column2).Distinct().Select(z1 => new
        {
            Level2 = z1,
            Level3List = list.Where(m => m.Column2 == z1).Select(n => n.Column3)
        })
    }).ToList();

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsonResult = serializer.Serialize(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your all valuable support. i solved my issue with below lambda expression.

```
var disp = menu.GroupBy(a => a.col1).Select(b => b.First()).Select(c => new BL.Objects.menu()
{id = c.id,
name = c.col1,
items = menu.Where(f => f.col1 == c.col1).GroupBy(g => g.col2).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).Select(j => new BL.Objects.submenu()
{id = j.id,
name = j.col2,
items = menu.Where(k => k.col2 == j.col2 && k.col1 == c.col1).Select(l => new BL.Objects.sub_submenu()
{id = l.id,
name = l.col3
})
})
});

    var jsonResult = System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize((disp);
```